# Android testing via spoon not equal test counts

Tags: android, android-testing, spoon, spoon-gradle-plugin

I am trying to use spoon for parallel running instrumental tests on all connected devicesю In my situation I have 3 connected devices at the same time now. 
I have about 96 tests at all. And for two devices I can see in test html spoon report that all test is run, but for one only 53 is run. See picture below:

[image]

Did anyone face the same behavior? Any ideas why it can happened?

Comment: What happens when you run tests for just that one device?